# When I try to read from a file, the first and third words of the file are skipped for some reason

Tags: c++, file-io

In my program I'm trying to read from some files, store the data into structs, and sort/display the data for an assignment. However, it wasn't quite working right, and after some troubleshooting I noticed that from every read file, the first and third words are skipped for some reason.

The relevant code:

```
void fillArray(string filename, string arr[])
{
    ifstream ifile(filename);
    int count = 0;
    while (getline(ifile, arr[count++]))
    {
        getline(ifile, arr[count]);
        count++;
    }
    ifile.close();
}
```

The relevant files are structured that after every word there's a newline, so getline only gets and stores one word per iteration. Also, it may be relevant as well that the files being read from are entered as arguments via the command prompt.

Comment: This loop makes no sense ar all. If you have one word per line, you just do `while(getline(ifile, arr[count++]));` Why both `>>` and `getline` to the same destination?

Comment: Haha, I'm still pretty new. I'll edit it and see if that helps.

Comment: Related: [Why does std::getline skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   while (ifile >> arr[count])
    {
        getline(ifile, arr[count]);
        count++;
    }
```

`ifile >> arr[count]` reads a word & without count being incremented, `getline` reads the rest of the line & overwrites what was read by `ifile >> arr[count]`

That may be the cause of some words being skipped - the words read by `>>` are overwritten.

Comment: So I tried replacing `ifile >> arr[count]` with `getline(ifile, arr[count++])` in the condition and it works now! Thanks a ton.